# Handling Silverlight not installed cases for dynamically loaded xap

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Our application is  dynamically loading silverlight application to an ASP.NET panel after the user chooses the options from the host ASP.NET page by (`Panel.Controls.Add(myHtmlGenericControl)`)

If silverlight is not installed or if the SL version is not correct, it doesn't prompt the user to install/update silverlight as it shows for statically added silverlight content. As a result of this some of the new users of the system will not have a clue if silverlight is not installed. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for my bad english)

Maybe you could test if silverlight is installed using [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs), and warn the user before adding the content.